# How to append script path strictly before closing body tag using jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, append

How do I force a script to exist in last position inside the closing body tag `</body>` using jQuery.

I tried the below:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>append demo</title>
  <style>
  p {
    background: yellow;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>I would like to say: </p>
 
<script>
$( "body" ).append( ' <script src="myscripts2.js"><\/script> ' );
</script>
<script src="myscripts1.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

...but it returns

```html
<script src="myscripts2.js"></script> 
<script src="myscripts1.js"></script> 
</body>
```

instead of:

```html
<script src="myscripts1.js"></script> 
<script src="myscripts2.js"></script> 
</body>
```

Comment: Why does it matter? When you add scripts dynamically, they're executed in the order they're added, not the order in the DOM.

Comment: The problem is that your script that appends is running before the DOM is fully loaded. At the time that it appends, `myscripts1.js` hasn't been loaded into the DOM yet. Put your code inside `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use `$.getScript()`?

Comment: Yes. I've no idea how to use $.getScript() for this

Comment: Just `$.getScript("myscript2.js")`

Comment: Does getScript make it so you can nominate the last script that gets loaded on a page. I have a Drupal install but when logged in js gets injected and rendered before `</body>` from the admin menus that break my webpage. To fix this I need to set a specific theme js file as the very last one that loads before the closing `</body>`

Comment: As above, put it in `$(document).ready()`, so it runs after the DOM is loaded and all the static scripts are run.

Comment: Nice! Thanks @Barmar. That did the trick!